# Find absolute cell location of a vlookup reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I extract the location (row & column) of where a vlookup function located the specified value? I am trying to locate which row of a spreadsheet a key word is found so that I may then use it as the absolute cell reference to increment to pull subsequent data

Answer (score 1):

Lookup functions can return either a location or a value at a location, depending on which one you use.  VLOOKUP returns a value.  You want to use another function that performs the same lookup as VLOOKUP but returns the location.  MATCH does that.

Both VLOOKUP and MATCH work with relative locations--you define a range where the action will take place and the selection is relative to that range.  With VLOOKUP, this isn't really an important distinction because it returns the actual value.  MATCH returns the position relative to the range you define.  So if you define a range that is between row 5 and row 10, and MATCH finds what it is looking for in the third row of the range, the absolute row would be 7.  You would need to add in the count of rows before the range.

So if you are looking in A5:A10 for "XYZ", the formula for the absolute row number it is in would be:

```
    =MATCH("XYZ",A5:A10,0)+4  or  =MATCH("XYZ",A5:A10,0)+ROW(A5)-1
```

Like VLOOKUP, you have to tell MATCH what type of lookup to use.  The `0` as the last parameter means to use an exact match.

This [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) will give you more detail on the MATCH function.

The column where the target is found is the column you define in the range.  If you want to use the result as a cell reference to do something else, you could use a function like INDEX, OFFSET, or INDIRECT.